# Segmentation fault in C++ in macOS in code of spirally transversing matrix

Tags: c++

I am a beginner and cannot understand why my code is giving segmentation fault error please tell my mistake there are no other errors in the code. the error occurred in vs code in macOS device.the given code is for spirally transversing matrix

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
# define n 4
#define m 4
 void spiral(int r, int c,int arr[n][m])
 {
     int last_row=r-1 , last_col =c-1;
     int left=0, right = last_col;
     int top=0, bottom = last_row;
     

     while(top<=bottom && left<=right)
     {
         for (int i=left;i<=right ;i++){
             cout<<arr[top][i]<<" ";
         }
         top++;

         for(int i=top; i<=bottom;i++){
             cout<<arr[i][right]<<" ";
         }
         right--;
        if(top<=bottom){
         for(int i=right; i>=left;i++){
             cout<<arr[i][bottom]<<" ";
         }
         bottom--;
        }

         if(left<=right){
             for(int i=bottom; i>=top;i++){
             cout<<arr[i][left]<<" ";
         }
         left++;
         }


     }
   
 }
 int  main(){
     
     /*int arr[n][m];
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
             cin>>arr[i][j];
         }
     }*/
     int arr[n][m]={
         {1,2,3,4},
         {1,2,3,4},
         {5,6,7,8},
         {5,6,7,8},
     };
     spiral(n,m,arr);
     return 0;
 
 }
```

Comment: Before each array access, add a check to make sure the index is in range.  Spoiler:  it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to look carefully at your code. For instance look at this loop, half way through your function

```
for(int i=right; i>=left;i++){
    cout<<arr[i][bottom]<<" ";
```

When you get here `right` equals 2, and `left` equals 0. So  `i` starts at 2, and keeps increasing, it's always bigger than `left`, so this loop continues 'for ever'. Very quickly `i` will be too big for the array you are accessing so you get an access violation.

I *guess* you meant to write this

```
for(int i=right; i>=left;i--){
```

but I'm not sure.

Sometimes all that you need to do is look carefully at your code and see that what you actually wrote is different from what you thought you wrote.

BTW you have the same mistake here

```
for(int i=bottom; i>=top;i++){
```

perhaps, again I'm guessing, you meant

```
for(int i=bottom; i>=top;i--){
```